# QCustomPlot in real time in an ECG style

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I want to make a real time graph to plot the data from my Arduino and I want to use the following function from QCustomPlot to plot the graph in an ECG style (starting again after few seconds and replacing the previous data):

```
void QCPGraph::addData(const QVector<double> &keys, const QVector<double> &values)`
```

with `keys=time` and `values=data` from serial port.

I already have the serial data and a graph that is continuous but I don't know how to modify this with the function above and make time vector.

Can you give me an example of how to call that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, you have a graph that it's `xAxis` range is constant. Lets say it is defined as `MAX_RANGE` seconds, and you want that once it passes `MAX_RANGE` seconds it will clear the graph and start over again from `0` sec.

If all this is right then I guess you already have a function that you are calling once every `T` seconds in order to update the plot. If not then take a look at [this example](http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/demos/realtimedatademo).
Lets assume that you already have a function that you are calling every `T` seconds:

```
void MyPlot::updatePlot(int yValue)
```

Then simply add a `timeCounter` as a class variable that will be updated every call. Then add an `if` statement that will check if it passed `MAX_RANGE`. If it did then clear the graph using [`clearData()`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPGraph.html#ad4e94a4e44e5e76fbec81a72a977157d), add the new value and reset `timeCounter`. If it didn't then just add the new value. Simple example (just make the changes to fit for your case):

```
void MyPlot::updatePlot(int yValue){
    this->timeCounter += T;
    if (this->timeCounter >= MAX_RANGE) {
        ui->customPlot->graph(0)->clearData();
        ui->customPlot->graph(0)->addData(0, yValue);
        this->timeCounter = 0;
    }
    else {
        ui->customPlot->graph(0)->addData(this->timeCounter, yValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the example that I am using. I will try to modify it with what you told me, thank you!

Comment: If this helped you solve your issue please accept it as the correct answer by clicking the *V* mark on the side of my answer.

Comment: I don't know where is T in that example

Comment: If you are calling your function using a `QTimer`. Then `T` is defined to be the time you set your timer for timeout. Such as `dataTimer.start(T)`.